# Google Place Picker API Query for App-scoped Places?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have recently been looking at the following [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/placepicker) to add to my application. It is the Google Place Picker API. I also know how to add places to the list of places that the Place Picker API uses to query for so that my custom places can appear in Place Picker API. However, I want it so that the Place Picker API only queries for just the places that have been created only by my application, and not for any other places that the Google Places API provides. I have found that this example [query](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=qgYvCi0wMDAwMDA5YzM4MTU5MTA0OjgwOGY3YzZkYjdiOmMwZmZmYzdjNTE1YmRjYmI&key=AIzaSyAkc1XoHTu4vYShCHJxivUM4wfsjULXyKk), under the `scope` key, helps me find if the Place created was created via my app or by Google. I want it so that the Place Picker API queries only for the Places created by my app. Is there any way to do this? That would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using place picker if you implement it in your custom way you can do it easily !  In the Google places API response you can search for   "scope" : "APP" the scope variable will be available in `alt_ids` If it gets google scope   Here is a sample response:  "results" : [
      {
        "place_id" : "BBB",
        "scope" : "GOOGLE",
        "alt_ids" : [
          {
            "place_id" : "AAA",
            "scope" : "APP",
          }
        ],
      }
    ]

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H hm where is `alt_ids`? and if I do do it my custom way, how will you implement the tableview that slides up and down, and also correlates with the places on the map?

Comment: You can see that in the response which I have mentioned ! You can implement custom one using UITableView,UISearchBar,UIPickerView and Maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible, sorry.  Neither the iOS or Android Place Pickers have an option to do this.

In fact both the Android [Place](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place) class and the iOS [GMSPlace](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_place) class lack the `scope` property, which only exists on the [Places API web service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details#PlaceDetailsResults) today.

You'd have to build this yourself, e.g. by displaying a map and adding markers to it for your places, etc, rather than using the Place Picker widget from the Google Places API for iOS (or Android).